# How to extract uniform noise from the mixture distribution

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, filter

Let $X$ be a sample from the distribution which is the mixture of the useful signal with the distribution $\xi(\theta)$ and a uniform noise $U[a, b]$. The probability of observing $U[a, b]$, the parmeters $a$ and $b$ are not known.

I would like to estimate $\theta$. How do I do it?

By the mixture I mean weighted average of probability density functions

Comment: "Mixture" refers to weighted average of probability density functions. Is that what you mean, or simply that $X = Signal + noise$?

Comment: Do you want to do this from a classical frequentist style inference (i.e. MLE) or is it ok to do it from teh Bayesian point of view?

Comment: So that you can comment and edit your own question, Volodymyr, please [merge your account](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) with user29514.